# how to set an array to a variable?

Tags: php, cakephp

Can anybody help me to store the below as an array?

I got the result as

```
Array (
    [TblCollectionReference] => Array ( 
            [content] => Array ( 
                    [0] => PBA_CA_FTL00003
                    [1] => PBA_CA_FTL00006
            )
    )
)
```

Now i need the 15 digit code.

individually i can get the code as

```
$this->data['TblCollectionReference']['content'][0]
```

But how to store it as array?

Comment: Do you want to store each digit as an element of the array?

Comment: you find PBA_CA_FTL00003, which is probably is defined as a string if its 15 digits long - what is it you'd want to store precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php)

```
$toStore = json_encode($this->data['TblCollectionReference']['content']);
```

and then you user `json_decode()` where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SerializableBehavior by CakeDC for handling this almost automatically. You can find it at https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/master/Model/Behavior/SerializableBehavior.php

I think this is what you are looking for. It basically does what Mihai Iorga suggested above... in a reusable way